# Using map vs flatmap for object

Tags: scala, mapping, flatmap

Given that I have a class

```
class Vehicle(name: String, model: String, age: Int, color: String)
```

and a Sequence/List

```
Seq[Vehicle]
```

Could someone help me with concrete/real-world use case where I would need a `map`, and a `flatmap`?

This may be an elementary question - but am yet to find a good example with objects/class use case.

Comment: If you have a function that for each `Vechicle` produces a single value, like getting its `model`, then you use `map` - If rather, you have a function that for each `Vehicle` produces multiple values, like for each `Vehicle` listing all its owners, then you use `flatMap` - Is just a matter of reading the types.

Comment: Let's say you have this `List[Vehicle]`. You need to learn what are all possible car names in this list. You should also use only cars younger than 10 years for this. How would do it if you are forbidden from using: `var`, `while`, and mutable collections? Treat this like an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

`map` and `flatMap` are not exclusive to collections. You can find those methods in classes like [Option](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Option.html#flatMap%5BB%5D(f:A=%3EOption%5BB%5D):Option%5BB%5D), [Try](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/util/Try.html#flatMap%5BU%5D(f:T=%3Escala.util.Try%5BU%5D):scala.util.Try%5BU%5D), [Future](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/concurrent/Future.html#flatMap%5BS%5D(f:T=%3Escala.concurrent.Future%5BS%5D)(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future%5BS%5D).

---

Let's think in "some real examples" for collections:

- A company that rent cars only to other companies
- A monthly report that list all the companies and how many vechiles were rented in a specific month with the columns **company** and **vehicles rented**
- A monthly report for listing all the rented vehicles and which company rented each one with the columns **company**, **vehicle registration plate** and **model**

Our models could look like

```scala
case class Vechicle(plate: String, model: String)
case class Company(name: String, vehiclesRented: Seq[Vechicles])

case class ReportTotalVehiclesRentedByCompany(company: String, totalVechiclesRented: Long)
case class ReportRentedVehiclesByCompany(company: String, plate: String, model: String)
```

A repository that returns a collection of companies who rented vechiles during some month

```scala
trait RentedVehiclesRepository {
  def getTotalRentedVehicles(month: Month): Seq[Company]
  def getRentedVehicles(month: Month): Seq[Company]
}
```

Then a service which returns the report we need

```scala
class RentedVehiclesService(repository: RentedVehiclesRepository) {
  def getTotalRentedVehiclesByCompanyReport(month: Month): Seq[ReportTotalVehiclesRentedByCompany] =
    repository
      .getTotalRentedVehicles(month)
      .map(company => 
        ReportTotalVehiclesRentedByCompany(company.name, vehiclesRented.size)
      )

  def getRentedVehiclesByCompanyReport(month: Month): Seq[ReportRentedVehiclesByCompany] =
    repository.getRentedVehicles(month)
      .flatMap(company => // <- here we have the `flatMap`
        company
          .vehiclesRented
          .map(vehicle => // <- here we have the `map`
            ReportRentedVehiclesByCompany(company.name, vehicle.plate, vehicle.model)
          )
      )
}
```

First we have a method with the signature

```scala
def getTotalRentedVehiclesByCompanyReport(month: Month): Seq[ReportTotalVehiclesRentedByCompany]
```

from the repository we have this one

```scala
def getTotalRentedVehicles(month: Month): Seq[Company]
```

We need to transform what we received from the repository because it's not enough to produce the report. What we want here is to transform a `Seq[Company]` in `Seq[ReportTotalVehiclesRentedByCompany]`. Being more abstract would be from a `List[A]` produce a `List[B]`. An simple example could be transform a `List[Int]` into `List[String]` just using `toString` method. Comparing **OOP** vs **FP**:

- **OOP** (using mutable objects)

  1. create new collection
  2. iterate the original one using a **for loop**
  3. **transform** each **element** inside the loop
  4. **add** the **transformed element** to the **new collection** created
  5. **return** the **new collection**

     ```scala
     def transform(input: List[Int]): ListBuffer[String] = {
       val newCollection = ListBuffer.empty[String]
       for(i <- input) newCollection += i.toString
       newCollection
     }
     ```
- **functional programming** (using immutable values):

  1. create a function with two parameters (one for the original collection, the second one to accumulate the result)

     ```scala
     def transform(input: List[A], accumulator: List[B]): List[B]
     ```
  2. call the function passing the original collection and the default result (in this case an empty collection)

     ```scala
     val inputList = List(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
     val listTransformed: List[String] = transform(inputList, List.empty[String])
     ```
  3. use pattern matching to split the collection in first element and the rest of the collection

     - if the first parameter is a non empty collection

       1. call the function recursively
       2. pass all the elements of the original collection except the first one as the first parameter
       3. create a new collection containing all the elements in the accumulator plus the new transformed element and use it as the second parameter
     - if the first parameter is an empty collection (means that we don't have nothing else to iterate)

       1. return the result accumulated in the second parameter of the function

     ```scala
     def transform(input: List[Int], accumulator: List[String]): List[String] =
       input match {
         case Nil => 
           accumulator
         case head :: tail => 
           val elementTransformed = head.toString
           val newCollectionWithTheNewElement = accumulator :+ elementTransformed
           transform(tail, newCollectionWithTheNewElement)
       }
     ```

As I mentioned before, collections have the method [map](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/Seq.html#map%5BB%5D(f:A=%3EB):CC%5BB%5D) that **builds a new sequence by applying a function to all elements of this sequence**. Which is what I did in the functional programming example.

Backing to our example of transforming a `Seq[Company]` to a `Seq[ReportTotalVehiclesRentedByCompany]`, we can just use `map` to do it. We only need the name of the company and the size of the list of rented vehicles.

In the second report, we have to do something similar, but the problem is we have a collection inside our input collection. If we use `map` instead of `flatMap` our result will be a collection of collections (`List[List[A]]`).

```scala
    repository
      .getRentedVehicles(month) // returns a Seq[Company]
      .map(company => // <- using a `map` instead of `flatMap` 
        company
          .vehiclesRented // a Seq[Vechicles]
          .map(vehicle => // returns a Seq[ReportRentedVehiclesByCompany]
            ReportRentedVehiclesByCompany(company.name, vehicle.plate, vehicle.model)
          )
      ) // the result is a Seq[Seq[ReportRentedVehiclesByCompany]]
```

A simpler example in this case could be a `List[List[Int]]` transformed to `List[String]`

```scala
def transformNestedList(input: List[List[Int]]): List[String] =
  input
    .flatMap( nestedList => 
      nestedList.map( number => number.toString)
    )
```

We can observe:

- `map` transforms a `List[A]` in a new `List[B]`
- `flatMap` transforms a `List[List[A]]` in a new `List[B]`

The `flatMap` method applies a `map` to the element of the collection and then `flatten` it.

```scala
def transformNestedList(input: List[List[Int]]): List[String] =
  input
    .map( nestedList =>
      nestedList.map( number =>
        number.toString
      )                 // <- returns a List[String]
    )                   // <- returns a List[List[String]]
    .flatten            // <- returns a List[String]
```

---

As it was mentioned at the beginning, `map` and `flatMap` are not exclusive to collections. They come from the [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) where we have `functions` with `input` and `output` instead of `objects` with `methods`.

- `map` is related with [Functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor_(functional_programming))

```scala
trait Functor[F[_]] {
  def map[A, B](a: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]
}
```

- `flatMap` is related with [Monad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming))

```scala
trait Monad[F[_]] {
  def apply[A](a: A): F[A]
  def flatMap[A,B](a: F[A])(f: A => F[B]): F[B]
}
```

The `F[A]` could be think as some kind of container and its API is just `map`, `flatMap` and `apply`. The `apply` method is just for creating `F[A]`, `map` and `flatMap` are the only way to operate over the `F[A]`. If we think in concret examples of `F[A]` we could mention `Seq[A]`, `Option[A]`, `Try[A]` and `Future[A]`. Each of them represents a concept.

- [Option](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Option.html): represents the absence of a value. It could be `None` if there is **no value**, it could be `Some(value)` when the **value is present**.
- [Seq](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/Seq.html): represents a sequence of elements. It could have **no elements** at all **or** it could have **at least one**.
- [Try](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/util/Try.html): represents a computation that can fail. The operation could be `Success(value)` when **succeed** or it could be `Failure(exception)` when it **failed**

Instead of directly interact with their internal values and asking if they represent one state or the other, you can use `map` or `flatMap` to operate them and you don't care about the state.

An "real example" using an `Option` could be when you have to gather values from different repositories, each repository can bring you the value if the previous one returned a value, if not just return a default value.

```scala
class Service(repo1: Repo1, repo2: Repo2, repo3: Repo3, repo4: Repo4) {
  def find(input: Input): Value = {
    val couldBeAValue1: Option[Value1] = repo1.find(input)
    val couldBeAValue2: Option[Value2] = couldBeAValue1.flatMap(value1 => repo2.find(value1))
    val couldBeAValue3: Option[Value3] = couldBeAValue2.flatMap(value2 => repo3.find(value2))
    val couldBeAValue4: Option[Value4] = couldBeAValue3.flatMap(value3 => repo4.find(value3))
    val valueToBeReturned: Value = couldBeAValue4.getOrElse(defaultValue)
  }

  // the previous code could rewrriten using for-comprehension which is 
  // just syntax sugar. The compiler will transform the for-comprehension 
  // in the above code 
  def findForComprehension(input: Input) =
    val couldBeAValue4 = for {
      value1 <- repo1.find(input)
      value2 <- repo2.find(value1)
      value3 <- repo3.find(value2)
      value4 <- repo4.find(value3)
    } yield value4
    val valueToBeReturned: Value = couldBeAValue4.getOrElse(defaultValue)
}
```

As you can see, instead of asking to each `Option` value if it is `Some` or `None` we just don't care. We only use `flatMap` and pass the transformation we want to apply as a parameter of the function. If one of them return a `None`, we will get a `None` and the following operations will not be executed. The same happens with `List`. It doesn't matter if it is empty or not. You just apply all the opertions you need using `map` or `flatMap` and at the end you extract the final value you got.

---

These two courses from coursera can help to understand more about these functional concepts

- [Functional Programming Principles in Scala](https://www.coursera.org/learn/scala-functional-programming?specialization=scala)
- [Functional Program Design in Scala](https://www.coursera.org/learn/scala-functional-program-design?specialization=scala)

Answer (score 0):

Both `map` and `flatMap` are higher-order functions in Scala that can be applied to collections like lists, sequences, or arrays. They are used to transform the elements of a collection based on a given function.

`map` takes a function and applies it to each element of a sequence, returning a new sequence with the results of the function. For example, if you have a sequence of vehicles, you could use `map` to convert each vehicle object to a string with its name only.

```
class Vehicle(val name: String, val model: String, val age: Int, val color: String)

val vehicles = Seq(
  new Vehicle("Honda", "Civic", 2023, "Red"),
  new Vehicle("Toyota", "Corolla", 2022, "Blue"),
  new Vehicle("Suzuki", "Swift", 2021, "Black")
)

val vehicleNames = vehicles.map(vehicle => vehicle.name)
println(vehicleNames)
```

The output is a sequence of strings, with one string for each vehicle in the original sequence:
`List(Honda, Toyota, Suzuki)`

`flatMap` is similar to `map`, but it allows for transforming each element into a collection of elements. It expects the provided function to return a collection (sequence, list, or array) rather than a single element. `flatMap` then flattens the resulting collection into a single collection by concatenating all the sub-collections. Use `flatMap` when you want to transform each element into multiple elements or when you want to flatten nested collections. For example, if you have a sequence of vehicles, you could use `flatMap` to convert each vehicle's name to its character parts.

```scala
val vehicleParts = vehicles.flatMap(vehicle => vehicle.name)
println(vehicleParts)
```

The output of this code is a sequence of all the character parts of names of all the vehicles in the original sequence. Quite meaningless but to demonstrate the `flatMap` function:
`List(H, o, n, d, a, T, o, y, o, t, a, S, u, z, u, k, i)`

To illustrate both `map` and `flatMap` together, try below code:

```scala
val vehicleList = vehicleNames.flatMap { name =>
  vehicles.filter(_.name == name).map(vehicle => s"${vehicle.name} - ${vehicle.model}")
}
println(vehicleList)
```

`flatMap` operation is used to iterate over each `name` in the `vehicleNames` sequence. For each `name`, `vehicles.find(_.name == name)` is used to find the first vehicle with a matching name (`find` function returns an `Option[Vehicle]`). Then `map` is used to transform each matching vehicle into a string representation `"${vehicle.name} - ${vehicle.model}"`. The output is a list of formatted strings representing the vehicle name and model:
`List(Honda - Civic, Toyota - Corolla, Suzuki - Swift)`